# Creating a building based on citygml4j at LoD3 and LoD4

Tags: java, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I have been trying to generate a building model based on citygml4j at different levels of details. I could generate simple models up to LoD2. I want to add some more details like doors and windows and interior geometries to the models. Are there any sample java codes for creating a building at higher LODs?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The citygml4j object model closely follows the XML encoding of CityGML. So the CityGML XML schemas and the [CityGML specification document](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/citygml) are of help.

Check out the following CityGML snippet of a building having a wall surface and a door. To keep it simple, I have omitted any spatial or thematic properties.

```
<bldg:Building>
  ...
  <bldg:boundedBy>
    <bldg:WallSurface>
      ...
      <bldg:opening>
        <bldg:Door>
        ...
        </bldg:Door>
      </bldg:opening>
    </bldg:WallSurface>
  </bldg:boundedBy>
</bldg:Building>
```

Note that the `Door` feature is connected to the `WallSurface` through the `opening` feature property. Likewise, the `Building` feature has a `boundedBy` feature property that contains the `WallSurface`.

Now, simply build the same hierarchy with citygml4j objects.

```
// create building, wall surface and door
Building building = new Building();
WallSurface wallSurface = new WallSurface();
Door door = new Door();

// add door to wall surface through an opening property
OpeningProperty opening = new OpeningProperty(door);
wallSurface.addOpening(opening);

// add wall surface to building through boundedBy property
BoundarySurfaceProperty boundedBy = new  BoundarySurfaceProperty(wallSurface);
building.addBoundedBySurface(boundedBy);
```

Finally, add some geometry and attributes. For instance, add a `gml:MultiSurface` as LoD 3 representation of the `WallSurface`.

```
MultiSurface geometry = new MultiSurface();
// ... add surface members containing the vertices ...

// add geometry to the wall surface
wallSurface.setLod3MultiSurface(new MultiSurfaceProperty(geometry));
```

Again, how to construct the GML geometry objects closely follows the XML schema. citygml4j is shipped with a lot of sample code. Check out the [`BuildingCreator.java`](https://github.com/citygml4j/citygml4j/blob/master/samples/creating_citygml/src/BuildingCreator.java) sample that illustrates how geometries can be created. But you can also populate the geometry objects in different ways.

Hope this helps.